# Django with s3 buckets

Tags: python, django, mongodb, sqlite, amazon-s3

I have images on s3 buckets and will be adding more images to the s3 bucket with other processes running. The goal is to be able to view all these images and be able to sort these images according to their metadata on a website structure.

I am currently using django with the sqlite database, and I have seen ways to use s3 buckets for media uploads on django apps; however, I am looking to automate the process. How would I be able to automatically upload all the images being put on to the s3 bucket to the django web app I am trying to build?

Answer (score 1):

There are probably multiple ways to accomplish what you are looking for. If I were you, I'd start at the [boto library for python](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-examples.html). This will allow you to easily interact with your s3 buckets and content, and hook potentially hook a background batch process to download said images.